# Auto calibration with OpenCV 3?

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

I am trying to do a dense 3d reconstruction project using openCV.

I am receiving a series of images from an unknown camera and so I cannot use the chess board method to find the intrinsic parameters of the camera. and so I must do auto calibration.

I saw that openCV has some methods for auto calibration such as focalsFromHomography() from [this page](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/stitching/doc/autocalib.html).

After I find the features, match them and find the fundamental matrix is there a way I can calibrate the unknown cameras by doing auto-calibration (preferably by using OpenCV 3 for c++)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV has an example called "stitching_detailed.cpp" that uses autocalibration, it helped me, maybe it helps you